# JQuery Mobile content only shown on reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have an index.html containing the following:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#pagetwo" id="pagetwo">Page two</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#pagethree" id="pagethree">Page three</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pagethree">
    <div id="headerPageThree" data-role="header">
      <div data-role="main">
       <div id="anyDiv"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<body>
<html>
```

As you see, the navbar in index.html links between pagetwo and pagethree.

Furthermore I have an main.js

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('<select>').attr({'name': 'fuu','id': 'load-fuu',
        'data-native-menu': 'false'}).appendTo('#headerPageThree');
        $('<option>').html('Load').appendTo('#load-fuu');
        $('select').selectmenu();
});
```

Let's say I open index.html with Chrome. URL is

```
file:///C:/Users/index.html
```

Then I click on "Page three" in the navbar. URL is then

```
file:///C:/Users/index.html#pagethree
```

The problem is, that the styling of items like the selectmenu looks absolutely strange. It's transparent for example. I add more things than shown in the main.js example and some of them aren't even displayed. Meaning there is nothing where they should be.

But the most curious thing is, that if I press F5 on the page where URL is

```
file:///C:/Users/index.html#pagethree
```

, then everything is perfect. I don't get this.

What is the difference between pressing F5 on index.html and pressing F5 on index.html#pagethree?

Can anybody help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme must be set on the element, as it isn't being applied from the parent page.  I am not completely sure why though...

This can be done by adding the data-theme attribute when you create the select element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('<select>').attr(
     {'name': 'fuu','id': 'load-fuu',
      'data-native-menu':'false',
      'data-theme': 'a'
     }).appendTo('#headerPageThree');
          $('<option>').attr({'value': '1'}).html('Load').appendTo('#load-fuu');
  $('#load-fuu').selectmenu();
});
```

Lastly, if you would like, [a codepen example.](http://codepen.io/mckenzielong/pen/pJepZZ)

Edit: the point made about the option needing a value for selection is valid (though it will still theme properly after we add data-theme)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the regular jQuery document.ready, use the jQuery Mobile events like pagecreate;

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pagethree", function(){ 
    $('<select>').attr({'name': 'fuu','id': 'load-fuu',
        'data-native-menu': 'false'}).appendTo('#headerPageThree');
    $('<option>').attr({'value': '1'}).html('Load').appendTo('#load-fuu');
    $('select').selectmenu();
});
```

If you want your option to be selectable, give it a value attribute.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o8fhzjoL/)**